# Irreducible components of the variety $V(X^2+Y^2-1,X^2-Z^2-1)\subset \mathbb{C}^3.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I want to find the irreducible components of the variety $V(X^2+Y^2-1, \ X^2-Z^2-1)\subset \mathbb{C}^3$ but I am completely stuck on how to do this. I have some useful results that can help me decompose $V(F)$ when $F$ is a single polynomial, but the problem seems much harder even with just two polynomials. Can someone please help me?

EDIT: In trying to answer this question, I knew it would be useful to know if the ideal $I=(X^2+Y^2-1, X^2-Z^2-1)$ was a prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ but I'm finding it hard to describe the quotient ring. Is it a prime ideal?

Comment: Hint: $V(f, g) = V(f) \cap V(g)$.

Comment: @xyzzyz I tried that, it gives that $V = V(X^2+Y^2-1) \bigcap V(X^2-Z^2-1) $ and those two algebraic sets are irreducible because those polynomials are irreducible. But that doesn't seem to answer my question about decomposing the set because its $\bigcap$ instead of $\bigcup.$ Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The same question was asked a a few days ago, I have answered it there. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341000

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an ad hoc approach:

We know that a point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb C^3$ is in the intersection iff $x^2+y^2-1=0$ and $x^2-z^2-1=0.$ In particular, we must have $x^2+y^2-1=x^2-z^2-1,$ which we simplify to $y^2+z^2=0.$ Thus the point must lie on one of the two hyperplanes $V(Y\pm iZ),$ i.e., $y=\pm iz.$

On the other hand, suppose that $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2-1=0$ and $y=\pm iz.$ These imply that $x^2+(\pm iz)^2-1=x^2-z^2-1=0.$ Thus, we see that we can describe the intersection as $V(X^2+Y^2-1,Y-iZ)\cup V(X^2+Y^2-1,Y+iZ).$

Thus, we have reduced to finding the irreducible components of $V(X^2+Y^2-1,Y\pm iZ).$ The corresponding coordinate rings are isomorphic to $$\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^2-1,Y\pm iZ)\cong\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1),$$ which implies that $V(X^2+Y^2-1,Y\pm iZ)$ are irreducible.

Comment: +1, also because your first sentence  reminds me of [Captain Haddock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Haddock), Tintin's colourful friend :-)

Comment: "Blisterin' barnacles!" I'm amused to have reminded you of him, especially as Captain Haddock is my favourite character from the Tintin series!

Comment: Dear Andrew: I'm pleasantly surprised,  since I hadn't  expected ( given your English sounding first name) that you  even knew that hilarious character from a Belgian comic-book .

Comment: Dear @Georges, indeed I have a few of the comic-books, and watched the animated tv series as a child. All in English, however... I'm not sure whether Haddock said "blistering barnacles" in French :-)

Comment: I'm so sorry for all the trouble Andrew but I still can't complete the question. I can't see why the coordinate rings are isomorphic. By what map are they isomorphic, and how do you see such isomorphisms?

Comment: For example, in trying to show $$\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/( X^2+Y^2-1, Y+iZ) \cong \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1) $$ I tried the map $p(X,Y,Z) + I\mapsto p(X,Y, iY) + J$ where $I,J$ are the ideals on the LHS and RHS. I checked that this is well defined, a homomorphism and a surjection. But to show that it is an injection, I have to show that $$ p(X,Y,iY) = f(X,Y) (X^2+Y^2-1) \implies p(X,Y,Z) = g(X,Y,Z) (X^2+Y^2-1) + h(X,Y,Z)(Y+iZ).$$ Is that implication even true? If so, then I found an isomorphism but I wouldn't have been able to see this isomorphism without you, how did you see it?

Comment: I've managed to show the injectivity now too! But I still lack intuition for this result.

Comment: @KatieDobbs Dear Katie, if you would like to show that the claimed ideals are prime, please look at my answer below. Regards,

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I have posted an answer below clarifying Katie's doubts about the primality of the stipulated ideals. Fyi, this is an exercise in Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* in the section on the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Dear @Andrew Certainly it is true that one can try to show that each of those polynomials is reducible and derive a contradiction. Regards,

Answer (score 11):

$\newcommand{\rad}{\text{rad}\hspace{1mm}}
$

The ideal $(x^2 + y^2 - 1,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$ is equal to the ideal $(y^2 + z^2 ,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$. This is because 
\begin{eqnarray*} (y^2 + z^2) + (x^2 - z^2 - 1) &=& y^2 + x^2 - 1\\
(x^2 + y^2 - 1) - (x^2 - z^2 - 1) &=& y^2 + z^2. \end{eqnarray*}

Thus we get 
\begin{eqnarray*} V(x^2 + y^2 - 1,x^2 - z^2 - 1) &=& V( y^2 + z^2,x^2 - z^2 - 1) \\
&=& V\left( (y+zi)(y- zi),x^2 - z^2 - 1\right) \\
&=& V(y+zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1) \cup V(y-zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1).\end{eqnarray*}
Now we claim  that the ideals $(y+zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$ and $(y-zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$ are prime ideals.  I will only show that the former is prime because the proof for the latter is similar. By the Third Isomorphism Theorem we have 
\begin{eqnarray*} \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y+ zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1) &\cong& \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y+zi) \bigg/ (y+ zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1)/ (y + zi) \\
&\cong& \Bbb{C}[x,z]/(x^2 - z^2 - 1)\end{eqnarray*}

because $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y + zi) \cong \Bbb{C}[x,z]$. At this point there are two ways to proceed, one of which is showing that $x^2 - z^2 - 1$ is irreducible. However there is a nicer approach which is the following. Writing
\begin{eqnarray*} x &=& \frac{x+z}{2} + \frac{x-z}{2} \\
z &=& \frac{z + x}{2} + \frac{z-x}{2}\end{eqnarray*}
 this shows that $\Bbb{C}[x,z] = \Bbb{C}[x+z,x-z]$. Then upon factoring $x^2 - z^2 - 1$ as   $(x+z)(x-z) - 1$ the quotient $\Bbb{C}[x,z]/(x^2 - z^2 - 1)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[u][v]/(uv - 1)$ where $u = x+z, v = x-z$. Now recall that 
$$\left(\Bbb{C}[u] \right)[v]/(uv - 1) \cong \left(\Bbb{C}[u]\right)_{u} $$

where the subscript denotes localisation at the multiplicative set $\{1,u,u^2,u^3 \ldots \}$. Since the localisation of an integral domain is an integral domain, this completes the proof that $(y+zi,x^2 - z^2 - 1)$ is prime and hence a radical ideal.

Now use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to complete the proof that your algebraic set decomposes into irreducibles as claimed in Andrew's answer.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I am wrong, but it seems to me that you are using something like $I+(J\cap K)=(I+J)\cap (I+k)$, so a distributivity law for the sum, when $J,K$ are coprime. Which are the hypothesis to use this result?